# Calling overloaded stored procedures with both one variable and no variables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, overloading

I have a few examples in my code of overloaded procedures, but to take just one set, here are two logging procedures I have:

```
  PROCEDURE Log_And_Return
  IS
  BEGIN
    Handle ('when others', TRUE, FALSE);
  END Log_And_Return;

  PROCEDURE Log_And_Return(
    in_err_name   IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    Handle (in_err_name, TRUE, FALSE);
  END Log_And_Return;
```

The idea was that both of these procedures could be called from exception blocks. Depending on whether a parameter was supplied, another procedure would be called with either an expected error (as in the case of the procedure that took a parameters) or a when others Oracle error (as in the case of the procedure with no input).

To further explain what I mean, I use these in my PL/SQL like so:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT ID
  INTO   ID
  FROM   IDTable
  WHERE  ID = id_entered_by_user;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  ERR.Log_And_Return (in_err_name => 'id_not-found');
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ERR.Log_And_Return;
END;
```

So if the ID isn't found using the lookup above, the procedure executes the `NO_DATA_FOUND` block. The Handle procedure is eventually called and using the id_not_found parameter it is able to do a lookup on another table and output an appropriate error message to the calling program.

If another error occurs (`WHEN OTHERS`) then the Oracle exception is returned to the calling program instead.

At least that's the theory, anyway.

I can't seem to get it to work. When I try to compile the program, I am told:

```
PLS-00307: too many declarations of LOG_AND_RETURN match this call.
```

I get this for every single instance it is used in the code. Why is this? I'm assuming it has something to do with the procedure passing no parameters (does it perhaps pass a `NULL` or something like that?). I've experimented with removing the no-input-parameter procedure, to see if a  value *was* being passed anyway (like a `NULL`) but that didn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the `IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL` declaration; you're providing a default value for the parameter, making it optional. When you have a call like `ERR.Log_And_Return;` you could be calling your first version that takes no arguments, or calling your second version that has an argument but letting it pick the default. There's no way for the compiler to tell which you meant.

It doesn't look like you actually want the default in this case anyway; you'll always pass something, even if the argument is itself null, so defaulting isn't really gaining you anything. If you ever really did call it with no argument then you'd want the first 'when others' version anyway.

So just change the procedure spec and declaration to:

```
  PROCEDURE Log_And_Return(
    in_err_name   IN    VARCHAR2
  );
```

... without the default setting.

[SQL Fiddle with the default](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40fc6/2) that shows the PLS-00307, and another [SQL Fiddle without the default](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09b8f/1) that compiles successfully.

More generally if you have overloaded procedures or functions, the specifications have to be distinguishable either by having different numbers or types (or names, if you can call with named actual parameters) of non-defaulted parameters.

This is touched on [in the PL/SQL language reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00810); though in your example you can't get around it using differently named formal parameters since one version doesn't have any parameters at all.

Comment: And just like that, it all works. Thanks for this - very useful information!